# Instant Apps with both App Links and Deep Links

Tags: android, deep-linking

I have an Android Instant App that is launched through the URL https://example.com, and since I am the owner of https://example.com, I could verify the URL using Google Digital Asset Links.

Now I want to create a Deep Link to https://wikipedia.com, so if the Instant App is open, when the user clicks on a link to https://wikipedia.com, I can perform some actions.

But I am not the owner of https://wikipedia.com, so I can not verify the URL and use App Links, instead, I really need to use Deep Links.

I tried with the following AndroidManisfest.xml, but it doesn't work:

```
<application>
    <meta-data
        android:name="asset_statements"
        android:resource="@string/asset_statements" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter android:order="1" android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
            <data android:host="example.com" />
            <data android:pathPrefix="/app" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter android:order="2" android:autoVerify="false">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
            <data android:host="wikipedia.com" />
            <data android:pathPrefix="/.*" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="default-url"
            android:value="https://example.com/app" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

When I try to upload the Instant App to Google Play, they say to me that https://wikipedia.com is not a verified URL, but I can't verify https://wikipedia.com.

What can I do?

Comment: once you set auto verify as true, it is applied to all the url mentioned in your manifest file. Including libraries.